# Expired domain hijacked - recommended action?

Tags: domains, legal, domain-registrar, hijacked, expired-domains

I have a (non-technical) client who let their `.org` domain expire, and it has since been bought by a squatter. They own the `.com` domain and currently use that as their primary domain. The client is a nonprofit, and doesn't have spare cash to throw at the problem.

The hijacker of the `.org` domain simply has it redirect to another domain that points to an adult pornographic website. This is obviously bad for my client's reputation, and is rather fraudulent in my opinion.

I have done a WHOIS lookup on the domain, know the domain registrar, and researched the new owner and they seem to be prolific in this technique based on various news articles and archives. There are previously resolved disputes with this squatter using ICANN's Uniform Domain Name Dispute Resolution Policy

I see three options ahead of me:

1. Email the hijacker directly and politely request they return the domain
2. Contact the registrar and notify them of behaviour violating their Terms of Service in the hope they shut down the domain
3. File a claim a resolution service under ICANN's UDRP

I'm not a webmaster and definitely not experienced in dealing with hijackers/squatters. Can anyone advise?

Comment: The only argument you may have that I can see would be if the domain is a brand name. Being a non-profit, this is less likely. But still possible. Keep in mind that domain monetizers do not give a flying rip about jack and will likely just laugh their nether regions off if you contact them. But you can always try. If the domain name is a brand, you can sue, but call a lawyer who know this stuff. Not one who thinks they know this stuff. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is open to too much opinion and interpretation. There is no definite answer for the simple fact that the domain itself expired. So, how could it have been hijacked? Well, if he registered your best option and advice would be to contact this person as directly as you can and I would avoid any email contact. Try to get their phone number. I would then call him and behave as nice as possible and explain the situation in a way that it is showing that you would really like their cooperation. Done. If he agrees it's all good, if not, then you would have to seek other alternatives based on your client`s interest.

Answer (score 0):

There is a redemption period for the domain after it expires if it passed there is nothing can be done unless the name is a Trade mark or registered.

You have to check with your domain registrar or the web host that you took the domain from. Also you can check [UDNDRP](http://www.icann.org/dndr/udrp/policy.htm) at icann.org